# Проблема Django "GET /account/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Tags: python, django

Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как не пытался сам решить не могу.
Хочу сделать выход из профиля на Django

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('account/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

В html шаблоне сделал ссылку:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выйти</a>
```

Но в браузере выдаёт: Страница недоступна, а Django выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /account/logout/
Method Not Allowed: /account/logout/
[08/Jan/2024 16:48:02] "GET /account/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы добавили в settings.py в installed_apps приложение django.contrib.auth?

Comment: Да добавил ошибка не в этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в шаблоне такой вариант:

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">выйти</button>
</form>
```